# How to move instance_method with args from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, methods

I have following line code in my view:

```
<td> Model.some_instance_method(args) </td>
```

I would like to clear this. Below i paste whole code.

https://gist.github.com/3039144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't make it super clear as to what your objective is. Assuming you just want it to be more idiomatic rails code, something like this would be much cleaner:

```
class PinnedContent < ActiveRecord::Base

  def reports
    PinnedContentReport.where("pinned_content_id = ?", self.id).count
  end

end
```

In your view:

```
<% @reported_pinned_contents.each do |reported_pinned_content| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= reported_pinned_content.id %></td>
        <td><%= reported_pinned_content.reports %></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```